# How to set different locations for different select option values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can`t understand, how can i make different links for the same button (in contact form),
depending on the selected option value.

```
<select name="level" class="level form-control" id="level" required>
    <option value="1">A1</option>
    <option value="2">A2</option>
    <option value="3">B1</option>
</select>

(function ($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
    $(document).on('submit', '#contact_form_submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const name = $('#name').val();
      const phone = $('#phone').val();
      const level = $('#level').val();
      const email = $('#email').val();


      if (name && email) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'contact.php',
          data: {
            name,
            phone,
            level,
            email,
          },
          success(data) {
            $('#contact_form_submit').children('.email-success').remove();
            $('#contact_form_submit').prepend(`<span class="alert alert-success email-success">${data}</span>`);
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#phone').val('');
            $('#level').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            location.href = "https://www.qwerty.com";
            // $('#map').height('576px');
            $('.email-success').fadeOut(3000);
          },
          error(res) {

          },
        });
      } else {
        $('#contact_form_submit').children('.email-success').remove();
        $('#contact_form_submit').prepend('<span class="alert alert-danger email-success">All Fields are Required.</span>');
        // $('#map').height('576px');
        $('.email-success').fadeOut(3000);
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

So as you can see, now, if the user enters correct data, he will be redirected to some link, but i have to put the different links for different options.
I tried to play with 'if' , but without success.
Thanks.

Comment: How are the links to be defined?  Is it a single link with different options, eg `link.com?id=A` / `link.com?id=B` or are the links defined in the `select`, eg `<option value='link1.com'>link1</option>`?

Comment: Could be either `location.href = $("#level").val()` or `location.href = base_url + $("#level").val()`

Comment: Simple `if( level==1 ) { location.href = "https://www.qwerty.com"; } else if ( level==2 ) { location.href = "https://www.other.com"; } else { location.href = "https://www.3rdoption.com"; };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better also add code that you tried and that did not work. So we could check it for possible typos or misunderstandings. Simple IFs should work fine for you.

```
if(level == '1'){
  location.href = "https://www.qwerty.com";
}
if(level == '2'){
  location.href = "https://www.google.com";
}
if(level == '3'){
  location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com";
}
```